# Javascript canvas- is there an easier way to do it?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-animation

I want to work with HTML5 and the `canvas` tag, but without a interface like Flash provides animation is tricky.  Are there any WYSIWYG interfaces for the HTML5 canvas?  I saw that Adobe now has software that converts Flash to canvas, but the price is too high.

Comment: This is **not** 4chan. The tone of your questions should be that of a Wikipedia article. The purpose of this site is to serve as a work of reference.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Apples iAd development tool, [iAd Producer](http://developer.apple.com/iad/iadproducer/), since it's designed to do HTML5 advertising and animations. You'll need a Mac, of course.